# c# random string with letter then number x length

Tags: c#

I am looking to generate a random string that must be in the following format:

[LETTER][NUMBER][LETTER][NUMBER] etc. to a specific length

so far I have a random string generator, removing a few characters I do not want, any advice on how to achieve such a string would be greatly appreciated.

```
 public static string GenerateRandomString(int length)
 {
    const string chars = "ABCEFGHJKPQRSTXYZ23456789";            
    return new string(Enumerable.Repeat(chars, length)
                                .Select(s =>s[RandomHelper.StaticRandom.Instance.Next(s.Length)])
                                .ToArray());
 }
```

Comment: Advice on what?  Does it work?  What do you want to improve?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of detail, I have adjusted my requirements

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems like this would be easier with a `for` loop:

```
public static string GenerateRandomReference(int length)
{
    const string chars = "ABCEFGHJKPQRSTXYZ"; 
    const string ints = "23456789"; 
    var returnString = new StringBuilder(length);

    for (int currentIndex = 0; currentIndex < length; currentIndex++)
    {
        if (currentIndex % 2 == 0)
            //Random letter
            returnString.Append(chars[RandomHelper.StaticRandom.Instance.Next(chars.Length)]);
        else
            //Random number
            returnString.Append(ints[RandomHelper.StaticRandom.Instance.Next(ints.Length)]);
    }
    return returnString.ToString();
}
```

Using the counter mod 2 gets you the alternating behavior. A while would also work, but the `for` semantic makes more sense here.

Comment: Maybe a `for` loop instead of a `while`?

Comment: @MatthewStrawbridge agreed, that semantic does make more sense. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Would the downvoter like to comment? If you find my post "not useful" I would like to improve it.

Answer (score -1):

By keeping your limitations in terms of available characters, you can do the following.

I found clearer to separately generate the numbers or the letters, so you can combine them as you like.

As for the generation itself, you can use a simple while loop, or for loop.

```
 private static char GenerateRandomLetter()
 {
    const string chars = "ABCEFGHJKPQRSTXYZ";
    Random rnd = new Random(); // you can avoid this allocation, put it class member            
    return chars[rnd.Next(0, chars.Length - 1)];
 }

 private static int GenerateRandomNumber()
 {
   Random rnd = new Random(); // you can avoid this allocation, put it class member
   return rnd.Next(2, 9);
 }

private static string GenerateKey(int length)
{
    // use a StringBuilder if you have a lot of concatenations
    var sb  = new StringBuilder();
    bool doLetter = true;
    for(int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
     {
         sb .Append((doLetter ?  GenerateRandomLetter().ToString() : GenerateRandomNumber().ToString()));
         doLetter = !doLetter;
     }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Karim - this doesn't allow me to specify the length of the string required?

Comment: here you go, with a for loop

Comment: +1 for using functions, and because you now meet the requirements. The down votes should be reversed if you ask me.